# Decide the upload folder location of Multer middleware

Tags: node.js, express, multer

All:

I am new to Express.js, when I deal with file uploading with Multer (https://github.com/expressjs/multer), I specify a multer middleware object:

```
var upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'});
```

But one thing confuse me so much is:
No matter where I put this line code( either in sub router file, or app.js), it always creates "uploads" folder under project root( same folder with app.js, views, routes, public... located), even I change it to "./uploads/", it still creates uploads folder under project root.

This confuses me so much, cos when I compare this with require() function, it seems require() uses relative path based on where it is get called while multer is not? I wonder if my understand is correct? And how to change it to relative if mine is correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always specify an absolute path (that is relative to the current module) to remove any doubt:

```
var upload = multer({dest: __dirname + '/uploads/'});
```

Comment: Thanks, this absolute path works. But I am still wondering about the rule to decide relative path in multer, why I can not change upload folder location even I put that var upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'}); in different location?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be based on the value of `path.resolve()`.  Where path is defined as `var path = require('path')`.